# Data comes back incorrect onActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-intent

I have done this before with no problem, so I am probably missing something silly.

I am trying to start a secondary activity that creates a new Owner in my database and returns the owner's id.

In my first activity i am calling the second like so:

```
Intent new_owner = new Intent(this, AddOwnerActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(new_owner, REQUEST_NEW_OWNER, null);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
```

Then in my second Activity i am setting the result like so:

```
 Intent data = getIntent();
 Log.v("OWNER", "DATA sending: "+new_owner.getId()); // this logs a number like 13
 data.putExtra("owner_id", new_owner.getId() );
 setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
 onBackPressed();//this calls finish();
```

Finally in my first Activity my onActivityResult looks like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_NEW_OWNER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            setUpOwnerSelector();
            Log.v("OWNER", "DATA received: " + bundle.getInt("owner_id"));//this is ALWAYS LOGGING 0
            selectOwnerWithId(bundle.getInt("owner_id"));
        }
    }
```

I can see my new owner being created in the Database successfull and in my secondary activity it is  logging the right id when i set result, but my first activitity is ALWAYS logging 0 as the extra..

I have to be missing something small.. a second pair of eye would be appreciated

**First Activity**

```
package com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Data.DataSource;
import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Data.Models.Owner;
import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewDogActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private DataSource db;
    private ArrayList<Owner> owners;
    private ArrayList<String> owner_selector_items;
    private Spinner owner_selector;
    private EditText dog_name_field;
    private Button save_btn;
    private Button cancel_btn;

    public static final int REQUEST_NEW_OWNER =1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_dog);
        owner_selector = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.owner_spinner);

        save_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);

        cancel_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        db = new DataSource(this);
        try{
            db.open();
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        setUpOwnerSelector();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_NEW_OWNER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            setUpOwnerSelector();
            Log.v("OWNER", "DATA received: " + bundle.getInt("owner_id"));
            selectOwnerWithId(bundle.getInt("owner_id"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        finish();

    }

    private void save(){

    }

    private void selectOwnerWithId(int id){
        int position =2;
        Owner o;
        for(int i=0;i<owners.size();i++){
            o = owners.get(i);
            if(o.getId()==id){
                Log.v("MASTER","OWNER FOUND");
                position+=i;
            }
        }
        owner_selector.setSelection(position);
    }

    private void createNewOwner(){
        Intent new_owner = new Intent(this, AddOwnerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(new_owner, REQUEST_NEW_OWNER, null);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
    }

    private void setUpOwnerSelector(){
        owners = (ArrayList)db.getAllOwners();
        owner_selector_items = new ArrayList<>();
        owner_selector_items.add(getResources().getString(R.string.no_owner));
        owner_selector_items.add(getResources().getString(R.string.newOwner));
        for(int i=0;i<owners.size();i++){
            owner_selector_items.add(owners.get(i).getLast_name()+", "+owners.get(i).getFirst_name());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, owner_selector_items);
        owner_selector.setAdapter(spinnerCountShoesArrayAdapter);
        owner_selector.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 1) {
                    //TODO create new owner for result
                    createNewOwner();

                } else if (position > 1) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

**Second Activity**

```
package com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Data.DataSource;
import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.Data.Models.Owner;
import com.eliddell.clicktrainer.R;

public class AddOwnerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Owner new_owner;
    private Boolean startedForResult = false;
    private EditText first_name_field;
    private EditText last_name_field;
    private EditText phone_field;
    private EditText email_field;

    private Button save_btn;
    private Button cancel_btn;

    private DataSource db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_owner);
        if(getCallingActivity()!=null){
            startedForResult =true;
        }

        db = new DataSource(this);
        try{
            db.open();
        }catch (Exception e){}

        first_name_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname_field);
        last_name_field =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname_field);
        phone_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.telephone_field);
        email_field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_field);

        save_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                save();
            }
        });
        cancel_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
        finish();

    }

    private void save(){
        if(first_name_field.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.first_name_hint), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            first_name_field.requestFocus();
            return;
        }else if(last_name_field.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.last_name_hint), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            last_name_field.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        new_owner = db.createOwner(first_name_field.getText().toString(),
                last_name_field.getText().toString(),
                phone_field.getText().toString(),
                email_field.getText().toString());

        if(startedForResult && new_owner!=null){
            Intent data = new Intent();
            Log.v("OWNER", "DATA sending: "+new_owner.getId());
            data.putExtra("owner_id", new_owner.getId());
            setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void cancel(){
        if(startedForResult){
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

and just in case it is something to do with my build/target sdk:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eliddell.clicktrainer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: can you try instantiating a new Intent instead of using getItent?

Comment: Why you are calling super.onResume(); in OnActivityResult ?

Comment: I removed super.onResume() sorry, that was a mistake.. i initially tried new Intent()  but same result.. im going to edit my above question and include both activities in full..

Comment: question edited still same result..

Comment: please pardon the sloppy logs... this is a work in progress

Comment: I just tested a simple example and it worked.  Try adding a log entry after `overridePendingTransition()` and before `finish()` and make sure it's getting in there.

Comment: Also, try commenting out `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);` in the second activity and see if that helps in any way.

Comment: Tried commenting out the overridePendingTransition() and then even the finish() and i am getting the same result.. then even replaced the call to onBackPressed() with just finish(); same result still.. i am loosing my mind.. going to try a clean project and build..

Comment: Clean and rebuild, still no success..

Comment: Oh my.. figured it out.. the problem was that my Owner.class was returning a long not an int..   thanks for your help though, all